# MySql table have two or more columns have default date vaule CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,any Solutions?

Tags: mysql

if i have a table with two columns create_time and update_time,the data type is timestamp,then have default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,the sql code of created table  is:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_activity` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STARTDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ENDDATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
```

but it prompt
 `error:1293,there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or UPDATE clause.`

Comment: Why would you put the same value in startdate and enddate?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to accomplish having both the STARTDATE and ENDDATE populated with the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. However to fix your code try changing your data types to DATETIME like this:

```
**CREATE TABLE `t_activity` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `STARTDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ENDDATE` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);**
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html

Answer (score 0):

This limitation in Mysql:

> Previously, at most one TIMESTAMP column per table could be
>   automatically initialized or updated to the current date and time.
>   This restriction has been lifted. Any TIMESTAMP column definition can
>   have any combination of DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses. In addition, these clauses now can be used
>   with DATETIME column definitions. For more information, see Automatic
>   Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME.

Check This for more detail

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-5.html

Comment: For older versions of MySQL `BEFORE INSERT` trigger can be used to set initial value.